# Condtional select query if a value in coulmn is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-5.7

I have a table

[image: 1]

and I'm trying to write a `select` statement with `ifnull` condition for same `type` value like to get the result as shown in this table

[image: 2]

Below is the sql I have tried -

> SELECT
> type,
> memo,
> IFNULL( memo, type = type) memo_all,
> amount
> FROM
> table

But I get the same result as `memo` column in `memo_all` column with above query as can be seen in this table [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5La7m.png). Please find the sqlfiddle here with above query and table - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55c43f

What am I missing here? Is there any alternative way to get the result as shown in table [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arlGo.png)?

Comment: Your sample data contains pairs of rows with the same `type` and different `memo` where one of them is not empty string. Is it (only one non-empty memo value per type) absolute?

Comment: *I'm trying to write a select statement with ifnull condition* Your sample fiddle contains empty strings `''`. IFNULL() does not check for them.

Comment: Yes, it is absolute. You are right. My table has empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, here is an alternative to Gordon's answer which doesn't use window functions:

```
SELECT
    t1.type,
    t1.memo,
    t2.memo AS memo_all,
    t1.amount
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MAX(memo) AS memo
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY type
) t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm on MySQL 5.7 and Gordon's answer doesn't work. Would be great if there's a way to get this without `t2`. Some workaround for window functions of MySQL 8+.

Comment: @yogi See Gordon's latest edit, but note that even there you still need to use a subquery.  The version I gave above might outperform the correlated subquery option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.memo memo_all
FROM `table` t1
JOIN `table` t2 USING (type)
WHERE t2.memo != '';
```

Solution which uses one source table copy:

```
SELECT `table`.*, @tmp := CASE WHEN memo = '' THEN @tmp ELSE memo END memo_all
FROM `table`, (SELECT @tmp := '') variable
ORDER BY type, memo DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works but is there a way to do this without creating a temporary table `t2`?

Comment: @yogi ??? where do you find any temporary table? I use 2 copies of the source table - and this is not exotic. Moreover, I cannot imagine the method which allows to solve the task on your MySQL version without using 2 source table copies except using user-defined variable. See other 2 answers for your server version both uses 2 copies of source table too.

Comment: @yogi Solution which uses one source table copy and user-defined variable - added. Remember - this is fullscan.

Comment: Sorry, I referred 2nd copy of the source table as temporary table. No issues since it worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT type, memo,
       max(memo) over (partition by type) as memo_all
       amount
FROM table;
```

You want to "borrow" the value from another row.  A simple scalar function is not going to do that.  However, window functions provide this capability.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT type, memo,
       COALESCE(memo,
                (SELECT t2.memo
                 FROM table t2
                 WHERE t2.type = t.type AND t2.memo IS NOT NULL
                 LIMIT 1
                )
               ) as memo_all
       amount
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked on fiddle but I'm lower MySQL version :(

Comment: @yogi . . . I edited the answer.  You should provide such information in the question, using tags for instance.

Comment: Added relevant version tags. Thank you for the answer! :)